# Como obtener la imagen de una ruta para posteriormente comprimir su tamaño en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Los pongo en contexto, en mi pagina web tengo una galería de imágenes las cuales se cargan dinámicamente. Las imágenes son alojadas en un servidor en Linux, y los paths están guardados en una Base de datos, por lo que yo haciendo una simple consulta ya las recupero.

Tengo un problema y es que cuando carga la pagina web, la galería se carga con mucho volumen de imágenes (hablo de 50 imágenes por ejemplo), y cada una pesa entre 2Mb y 3Mb, haciendo que la pagina web tarde muchísimo en cargar.

Las imágenes son recuperadas desde la base de datos, como previamente mencione, y guardadas en una `List<PedidoModel>`, y finalmente enviadas a la vista.

Lo que estuve intentando es convertir la lista en un `byte[]`, y éste en un `Image`, pero esto no funciona ya que lo que tiene la lista son las rutas de las imágenes, pero no las imágenes en sí, y aparte de eso, `Bitmap` es solamente soportado en `Windows`.

Por ejemplo, esto fue lo que estuve intentando:

```
   List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;
    List<PedidoViewModel> nuevaListaPedidos;
    consulta = "miConsulta"
    listaPedidos = SelectConexionMySql(consulta);
    nuevaListaPedidos = ResizeImage(listaPedidos)
    
    private object ResizeImage(List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos)
            {
                Size size = new Size(100, 100);
                Image imagen, nuevaImagen;
    
                foreach(var ped in listaPedidos)
                {
                    imagen = stringToImage(ped.getImagenes());
                    nuevaImagen = new Bitmap(imagen, size);
                }
            }
    
            public Image stringToImage(string inputString)
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString);
    
                // Don't need to use the constructor that takes the starting offset and length
                // as we're using the whole byte array.
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true);
    
                return image;
            }
```

Tambien probando éste codigo que brinda Microsoft, pero lo mismo que `Bitmap`, `EncoderParameters` es solamente soportado en `Windows`:

```
private void VaryQualityLevel()  
    {  
        // Get a bitmap. The using statement ensures objects  
        // are automatically disposed from memory after use.  
        using (Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\TestPhoto.jpg"))  
        {  
            ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
  
            // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID  
            // for the Quality parameter category.  
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =  
                System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;  
  
            // Create an EncoderParameters object.  
            // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter  
            // objects. In this case, there is only one  
            // EncoderParameter object in the array.  
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);  
  
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);  
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;  
            bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);  
  
            myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);  
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;  
            bmp1.Save(@"C:\TestPhotoQualityHundred.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);  
  
            // Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.  
            myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0L);  
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;  
            bmp1.Save(@"C:\TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg", jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);  
        }  
    }

  private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)  
{  
    ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();  
    foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)  
    {  
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)  
        {  
            return codec;  
        }  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

Investigando encontré `ImageSharp`, también recomendada por Microsoft para el `resize` de la imagen, pero para esto lo mismo que antes, requiero de la imagen y no de la ruta.

Por lo que mi pregunta es, **¿Es posible transformar un `string` a un `Image` o `IFormFile` sin utilizar `Bitmap`?**

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Un problema adicional es el momento en que llamas a renderizar las imágenes, revisa lo que es LazyLoading, de preferencia, ten las imágenes expuestas en algún lado de la carpeta `wwwroot/img/` Por otro lado, estás procesando linealmente cada imagen para los resize, ¿has considerado investigar cómo usar el poder del CPU y sus hilos de ejecución? Si lo haces, revisa bien la documentación, ahí está prácticamente todo, cosa de intentar :D

Comment: No conocia LazyLoading ni nunca habia escuchado hablar de eso. Voy a investigarlo y ver cómo podria implementarlo en mi proyecto. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para servirles, saludos a Kamisama, Mr.

Comment: No entendí bien, lo que buscas es crear thumbnails, es decir, versión pequeñas de las imágenes originales?

Comment: No, lo que quiero es comprimirlas, es decir, que en vez de que pesen 2,000Kb, pesen por ejemplo 500Kb. Asi no es tan pesada y la pagina web se cargue mas rapido

Comment: En que formato están tus imágenes?

Comment: Las imagenes estan todas como JPG

Comment: Personalmente, lo que haría sería usar esta herramienta https://tinypng.com/developers tiene una API, podrías guardar la imagen original y generar la imagen optimizada. Cosa de evaluar costos y demás.

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el peso de imagen puedes cambiar sus dimensiones, cambiar su formato y/o cambiar la calidad.

Normalmente tu problema se aborda creando unas copias de menor tamaño a modo de thumbnails y luego al presionar una imagen se muestra la original.

Esto también de forma general se hace cuando se guarda la imagen, y no cuando se muestra. Para esto hay varios programas de consola, en lo personal utilizo GIMP y un plugin que se llama [BIMP](https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/), el cual me permite ajustar un lote de imágenes, incluyendo cambiar el porte y los formatos

Tu señalas que están en JPG y que no quieres cambiar el tamaño. Lamentablemente me parece que no hay forma de lograr resultados que sean mucho mejores. La única opción seria usar el formato webp, pero no es compatible con todos los navegadores, con este formato yo he obtenido resultados esplendidos en compresión.

Ahora bien, dado que tu pregunta como resolver esto con c# y asp mvc, te puedo dar una posible solución

1. Crear un controller Imagen, con una función que recibe la id de la imagen guardada en tu base de datos.

```
 [HttpGet("Get/{Id}")]
        public async Task<FileResult> GetImagen(int id)
        {
            var path = "ruta de la imagen obtenida desde la bd";
            var h = new HttpClient();
            var f = await h.GetByteArrayAsync(path);

            var ms = new MemoryStream(f!);
            var img = BajarCalidad(Image.FromStream(ms));
   

            MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms2.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(ms2, "image/jpeg");
        }

        public static Image BajarCalidad(Image source)
        {
            using (var target = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height))
            {
                using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);
                }

                return (Image)target.Clone();
            }


        }
```

La función BajarCalidad, para una prueba que acabo de hacer, tome un jpg de 1.14Mb y lo dejó en 646mb, pero supongo que esto puede variar según la imagen inicial, porque realmente la función solo copia la imagen.

Puedes variar el formato (png,gif,bmp) para ir probando, en la linea:

```
img.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

También puedes cambiar algunas opciones antes de g.DrawImage, pero yo cuando lo hice no vi diferencia

```
 using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target))
                {
                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
                    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
                   
                    g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);
                }
```

De todas maneras, te dejo una función para escalar la imagen manteniendo la proporción original

```
public static Image ResizeImageKeepAspectRatio(Image source, int width, int height)
        {
           
            if (source.Width != width || source.Height != height)
            {
                // Resize image
                float sourceRatio = (float)source.Width / source.Height;

                using (var target = new Bitmap(width, height))
                {
                    using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target))
                    {
                        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                        // Scaling
                        float scaling;
                        float scalingY = (float)source.Height / height;
                        float scalingX = (float)source.Width / width;
                        if (scalingX < scalingY) scaling = scalingX; else scaling = scalingY;

                        int newWidth = (int)(source.Width / scaling);
                        int newHeight = (int)(source.Height / scaling);

                        // Correct float to int rounding
                        if (newWidth < width) newWidth = width;
                        if (newHeight < height) newHeight = height;

                        // See if image needs to be cropped
                        int shiftX = 0;
                        int shiftY = 0;

                        if (newWidth > width)
                        {
                            shiftX = (newWidth - width) / 2;
                        }

                        if (newHeight > height)
                        {
                            shiftY = (newHeight - height) / 2;
                        }

                        // Draw image
                        g.DrawImage(source, -shiftX, -shiftY, newWidth, newHeight);
                    }

                    return (Image)target.Clone();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return (Image)source.Clone();
            }
     
        }
```

Finalmente en la parte de HTML pones algo como:

```
<img src="localhost/Image/get/{id} />
```

Siendo la id, la id que sacas de tu base de datos

Comment: Te agradezco el código y la explicación! pero para `BajarCalidad` estás usando `Bitmap` y yo no lo puedo usar, ya que es solamente soportado en Windows. Te agradezco y quizá a alguien  le funcione mas adelante.